# Handling duplicates that aren't exactly duplicates

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Just came across this vote to close:

[A movie about a lorry in space transporting robots?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/34385/a-movie-about-a-lorry-in-space-transporting-robots)

Now, as pointed out by Walt, the *answers* are duplicate.  However, the questions are different, and unless you know the movie you wouldn't know that.  Since both questions are searchable and don't cover the same aspect of the movie, shouldn't they both be left open?  Or do you close one of them after you point to the post with the answer?

And, if the proper answer is to close one of them, why?  Is it to save space on the servers?

Comment: TBH I tried to be more careful in the past with duplicate votes (e.g. when the descriptions vary or when the old answer isn't approved) but I kinda gave up on that due to ID overload, and now I just do it whenever I'm fairly convinced they're the same. We have lots of ID coming in and archived, I don't think we need it in *duplicates*.

Comment: While I tend to agree with *Walt*, I never was a big fan of SE's general policy of duplicate-voting based on answer rather than question and would leave it open when the questions are significantly different. But on the other hand, yeah, nobody wants 5 stupid ID questions asking for the same friggin' thing. It's a conflict of consistency vs quality and it's unfortunate that your example is actually an ID question (though, I don't think with other kinds of questions we have that particular problem you adress so much at all). But thanks for the meta question, even if I don't know the answer yet.

Comment: And frankly, we all know that *nobody never ever* searches for an ID question at all. They only are of use for the asker alone and noone else. So keeping 5 open versions of them around doesn't seem the best idea. ;-)

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Despite my opinion, if a rule is formed or some consensus is reached on the matter, I'll follow it.

Comment: Despite my dislike of ID questions, and the fact that no-one is likely to search for them (but we have no data to support that), it seems silly that these are regarded as duplicates.

Comment: Provided the duplicate questions have sufficient votes to not be deleted, I don't think there's harm in marking them as duplicates. If they're answered, the answers can still get upvotes and the question will remain on the site for others to search for... And, if there's more or better information on the existing question, then the two are linked and both answers can be viewed... I mean, unless we want to start an odd policy of retroactively tagging ID questions with accepted answers with the tag of the film/show title.

Comment: I was going to say, we have no proof for or against people searching for ID questions.  We probably do get some hits from google though, but I don't know if there's an easy way to show that.

Answer (score 1):

Because they're identification questions I'd regard them both as useless anyway.

From a purely objective point of view if you have two questions that are asking different things but both happen to result in the same answer, they're still both valid questions in their own right and should both be allowed to exist independently, potentially with a reference somewhere in the question/answer/comments linking to the other related questions (which would then result in that post appearing in the side bar for that post).